# Optimize SVG game

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

I have created my first SVG game, using [Raphaël.js](http://raphaeljs.com/).

In Chrome the game feels fast, but in other browser like IE (understandable since it's using VML), Firefox, iPad safari and others, it feels slow at times.

I'm looking for some tips on how I can optimize my code to squeeze out the absolute best performance. I've tried the best I can to optimize it myself, but I'm just a JS beginner. Also feel free to mention if should be using any recommended best practices I'm not using. Where is it probable that the bottleneck is?

You can see the code and try the game on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mofle/zgYRC/3/).

Comment: Seems not to work in Internet Explorer 8 and the latest Google Chrome.

Comment: Try again, think I fixed it, didn't seem to work in Safari either, something wrong with jsfiddle managed resources.

Comment: One optimization may be to switch to [ex]Canvas ;-)

Comment: Having separate speeds for each browser would help. The speed is perfect in Chrome, but it's way too fast in IE.

Comment: Oh, and my previous comments means that I find the game too fast in IE not sluggish at all. ie8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

reduce method calls

```
var left1 = a.attr('x'),
left2 = b.attr('x'),
right1 = a.attr('x') + a.attr('width'),
right2 = b.attr('x') + b.attr('width'),
top1 = a.attr('y'),
top2 = b.attr('y'),
bottom1 = a.attr('y') + a.attr('height'),
bottom2 = b.attr('y') + b.attr('height');
```

Could be optimized like so:

```
var left1 = a.attr('x'),
left2 = b.attr('x'),
right1 = left1 + a.attr('width'),
right2 = left2 + b.attr('width'),
top1 = a.attr('y'),
top2 = b.attr('y'),
bottom1 = top1 + a.attr('height'),
bottom2 = top2 + b.attr('height');
```

This saves you 4 method calls per `hitDetection` call. Same applies to `wallDetection` and probably other functions as well. In fact, I also believe you width and height calls can be removed and just cached through a closure, since those are pretty static after creation, see next example.

Also with the next bit:

```
var animateEnemies = function(enemy) {
    var enemyWidth = enemy.attr('width'),
    enemyHeight = enemy.attr('height'),
...
```

You set the width and height of the enemies once, so they seem pretty constant, you could remove the `.attr()` lookup and pass the width and height from the `createEnemies` call as well.

```
var animateEnemies = function(enemy , enemyWidth , enemyHeight) {
    var animationDuration = getRandomInt(1000, 3000) / difficulty;
    enemy.animate({
        x: getRandomInt(0, gameWidth - enemyWidth),
        y: getRandomInt(0, gameHeight - enemyHeight)
    }, animationDuration, "ease-in-out");
    // use setTimout instead of onAnimation callback, since it gave "too much recursion" in Firefox 3.6
    this.timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
        animateEnemies(enemy , enemyWidth , enemyHeight);
    }, animationDuration);
};
```

Reducing function calls and caching variables can help a lot in legacy browsers, other then that, code looks pretty neat.

Comment: Unfortunetely none of these micro optimizations will help.

Comment: @galambalaz When addressing legacy browsers such as IE, there's no such thing as micro optimisations... Reducing function calls within often invoked functions can actually offer a huge performance boost. If it solves the problem entirely however is unlikely, but it WILL HELP.

Comment: If the performance gain is unnoticable, it's micro optimization. Things that yield somewhat better results in theory and have no effect in a particular situation. This is why optimization should always go hand in hand with testing.

Answer (score 3):

I don't want to sound distressingly, but i doubt *IE* can do any better. 
As you can see I made a [stripped down version](http://jsfiddle.net/uX4RH/5/) consisting only the animations (no hit detection, game logic or `mousemove` handler) and the speed is still unacceptable.

For *Firefox* I think I found out [how](http://jsfiddle.net/2Dth9) to avoid sluggishness:

```
var mouseMove = function(e) {

    // only do this if there's at least 20ms diff.
    var now = +new Date();
    if (now - mouseMove.last < 20)
        return;
    else 
       mouseMove.last = now;

    // ...
};

mouseMove.last = +new Date();
```

Answer (score 1):

Minimize the number of DOM calls.